# Why cant I add to ListIterator while iterating over it?

Tags: java, loops, iterator

Im trying to add to a ListIterator while iterating over it but when checking if it worked hasNext() always returns false.

As [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html) states that a ListIterator is "An iterator for lists that allows the programmer to traverse the list in either direction, ***modify the list during iteration***, and obtain the iterator's current position in the list." however  when Im trying to add I'm neither getting an Error message nor is the ListIterator getting a new Element.

```java
public void foo() {
    List<String> bar = new ArrayList<String>();
    bar.add("foobar");
    ListIterator<String> quux = bar.listIterator();
    while(quux.hasNext()) {
        if(quux.next().equals("foobar")) {
            quux.add("baz");
        }
    }
}
```

At the end of this funtion I expect the ListIterator to contain the new String "baz". However when I call the hasNext() method it returns false. The program even got past the if-Statement it just turns out, that the add-method doesnt do what its supposed to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: I absolutely love persons who downvote Q/A without the slightest explanation. Continue like this, this is so useful.

Comment: It's not a duplicate of "string comparing".

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I agree with you, I received a downvote without explanation.

Comment: @LucienNestler You should not compare String with `==` but with `String.equals` instead. In this use case, it might work by chance (because of vm optimization) but the code is not valid

Comment: Im sorry but I didnt downvote anyone, I just clicked the button that said that this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Also @ArnaudDenoyelle I wanted to answer your comment but you deleted it beforehand, so I answered on user2342558 's answer

Comment: @LucienNestler I am sorry, my comment was not against you. I know it was not you because you were downvoted also :p

Answer (score 0):

Your code works (after fixed the missed `()` after `new ArrayList<String>` and replaced `==` with the correct method to compare strings, `equals`:

```
import java.util.*;

public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> bar = new ArrayList<String>();
        bar.add("foobar");
        ListIterator<String> quux = bar.listIterator();
        while(quux.hasNext()) {
            if(quux.next().equals("foobar")) {
                quux.add("baz");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(bar);
    }
}
```

returns:

```
[foobar, baz]
```

As you can see, `baz` were inserted.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, I added the missing () in the code for this site, but the objects Im comparing are not really Strings, I just used Strings to simplify the problem as I am using a self defined class and in fact Im getting inside the if-Branch where I call the add function just to see that nothing changes in the Iterator.

Comment: @LucienNestler You're welcome. Please flag my answer as accepted and upvote it. If you'll open a new question about this with the reral types I'll answer it

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you expect to be able to fetch the added element with `next()`:

> nor is the ListIterator getting a new Element
>
> [...]
>
> At the end of this funtion I expect the ListIterator to contain the new String "baz". However when I call the hasNext() method it returns false

However, the JavaDoc for
[ListIterator.add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add-E-) explicitly states that this is not the case:

> The new element is inserted before the implicit cursor: a **subsequent call to next would be unaffected**

---

If you want to include the element in the iteration you can rewind the list iterator by one position:

```
    if(quux.next().equals("foobar")) {
        quux.add("baz");
        quux.previous();
    }
```

Comment: Oh thanks, looks like I overread that, is there a way to iterate over also the new element?